# Assign same value to an instance's attribute

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

If the attributes of an instance are assigned with the same value, would `commit` result in writes to the database? I just wonder whether it's good practice to update attributes without checking whether that the existing value is actually different to the new value.

Comment: I can't tell for sure, but if it were like this, the implementation would really suck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ORM does value checks when flushing and creates updates only on changed values. Quoting the [documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/session.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.dirty):

> At flush time, the value of each attribute is compared to its
>   previously saved value, and if there’s no net change, no SQL operation
>   will occur (this is a more expensive operation so it’s only done at
>   flush time).

Comment: I see. So is it good practice to just assign the values in the logic without checking for net change? That is, push the checking work to sqla.

Comment: Sure. The logic is already in SQLAlchemy so why duplicate it.